# naming a bunch of file using java

Tags: java, file, naming

I want to rename a bunch of file using java code.
I have this code that renaming the files:

```
public class NamingTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // change file names in 'Directory':
    System.out.println("enter the directory");
    String absolutePath = keyboard.nextLine();
    File dir = new File(absolutePath);
    File[] filesInDir = dir.listFiles();
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("enter the constant name");
    String con = keyboard.nextLine();
    for(File file:filesInDir) {
        i++;
        String name = file.getName();
        System.out.println("enter the "+i+"next part");
        String nxt = keyboard.nextLine();
        String newName = i +"_"+ con + nxt+".pdf";
        String newPath = absolutePath+ "\\"+ newName;
        file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
        System.out.println(name + " changed to " + newName);
    }
} // close main()
} // close class
```

I have a problem in this code: the code save the new files in one step backword on the given directory and the new renamed files have the last directory name.

Example: the directory is "/Users/Omar/Documents/test",
the place where the named file saved is "/Users/Omar/Documents" and the named files have "test/" as prefix.

Real example: when code run he asked for the directory, I gave him a "/Users/Omar/Documents", then asked for constant name (that must be repeated on the all files) I entered "m a s_", then forever file he asked for the next name (it's different from file to other file).

I expect to get a file named with "(number)m a s_(nxt).pdf", in "/Users/Omar/Documents/ test".. but what the code gave is "/test/(number)m a s_(nxt).pdf".

AND I want to make a gui for it.

Note: I use Mac

Comment: *"note: I use Mac"* - note: I use coffee :-)

Comment: Can you please edit your question.  I am having serious difficulty understanding your English.  Perhaps you should 1) explain more clearly what the code is *supposed to do*, and 2) give clear examples of what it is actually doing wrong.

Comment: @StephenC I *might* use a debugger, but [Malcolm](https://youtu.be/H3Fd7a51P8o) solves his problems with a chainsaw (and he never has the same problem *twice*).

Comment: :D
really! ,and I thought have a good English XD

Comment: @StephenC is it clear now?

Comment: Well Omar, if you have good English skills then the problem is that you are not expressing yourself clearly.

Comment: No.  It isn't.  Please add some real examples.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I was using "use" in another sense ;-)

Comment: @StephenC now? :D

Comment: What is 'a punch of file'?

Comment: @EJP a 771 pdf files XD

Comment: @OmarDiab That means nothing. It's not even correct English. And what's this XD that you keep typing?

Comment: He means "a bunch of files".  His English is not as good as he thinks.

Comment: @OmarDiab Leaving that aside, it is not correct English to use :: as punctuation, or to use multiple colons in one sentence, or to put spaces before punctuation, or to omit them after it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the recommended way to solve problems like this is to use a debugger; e.g. set a breakpoint on the "renameTo" call and see what the actual argument and result are.

Looking at your code, I can see a couple of issues:

1. My understanding is that Mac uses "/" as the file separator, but your code uses "\".  I'm not sure if the Java runtime will transform the "\" to a "/" ...
2. The `File.renameTo(File)` method returns a `boolean` to say if the rename succeeded.  You are ignoring it.

I'm not sure if these issues are causing the "problem", but I don't have a Mac so I can't try out the code.

---

> AND I want to make a gui for it.

That is way too broad a question.  I suggest that you find and read a tutorial on how to implement GUIs in Java.

Comment: I edit the question with real example :: when code run he asked for the directory : I gave him a "/Users/Omar/Documents" , then asked for constant name(that must repeated on the all files)I entered :"m a s_", then for ever file he asked for the next name:(its different from file to other file). I expect to get a file named with "(number)m a s_(nxt).pdf" , in "/Users/Omar/Documents/ test".. but what the code gave is "/test/(number)m a s_(nxt).pdf"

Comment: If my points 1 and 2 don't solve your problem, then see the advice in the first sentence of my Answer.  Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your problem as I am not a Mac "user"  / addict :-)